# How to Remove or Clear EditText Focus on listview click android java

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, focus

Hi Everyone I want to remove or clear EditText focus when user click on ListView . Every Answer will be appreciated.

> When user click on listview it goes to fragment_detail.xml and I also put these atributes but not work.   android:focusable="true" 
>       android:focusableInTouchMode="true"

That fragment where user click I also put view.clearFocus(); but not work

Thanks for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

add below at your xml file.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <requestFocus/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this method only remove focus but not keyboard. How to remove keyboard also #Mehul Kabaria

Comment: you have to always hidden keyboard for that screen?

Comment: No I have focus keyboard for that screen

Answer (score 0):

I using this code. This code close keyboard and clear edittext focuse.
Try this;

```
editText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(URLText.getWindowToken(), 0); 
                    editText.setFocusable(false);
                    editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: should i call set this function in onViewCreated or somewhere else I am New don't mind

Answer (score 0):

I do it programmatically with, it removes focus and the keyboard.

```
editText.clearFocus();
editText.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);
```